# How to add "webpack.config.vendor.js" file in my angular 5 project

Tags: angular, webpack, .net-core, angular-cli

I've created an angular cli app then I've integrated it with a dotnet core 2 web api project. Everything is working good. When I wanted to add some css and javascript references to "webpack.config.vendor.js", I realized that there is not any configuration file for webpack so I googled it and found "ng eject". This command generated a webpack.config.js file for me but I don't know how to add "webpack.config.vendor.js" in my project.

thanks,

Comment: Is this a @angular/cli project? or did you create it from scratch?

Comment: @angular/cli one.

Answer (score 0):

In case for `@angular/cli` projects, you need to add your lib scripts to the scripts array in the scripts array of your app in `.angular-cli.json` file, the path must be relative to src folder, meaning that if it's in node_modules, you must add (bootstrap example) `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"` to your scripts array

For styles this would apply but for the styles array in the same file

Comment: If you need reference on the scripts array, you can find it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)

Comment: Thank you,
In this particular case, this worked as a work around for me but I need to have that file in my project.